# Required Field Indicator not working in IE7 and IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cakephp, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm using CakePHP's field validation and the standard CSS based 'required field' indicator (red asterisk) and it all works just peachy for all browsers except (of course) IE7 and IE6.

I seems they don't like the CSS that constructs the indicator.  I found a blog post by Mark Story (here http://mark-story.com/posts/view/hacking-the-cakephp-formhelper-adding-required-indicators) from 2008 that suggests hacking the Cake code to display it correctly.  This having been more than 2 years ago, I would hope that a better solution has been created for this or that it had been addressed somehow in the newer versions of Cake released by then. IT's such a standard thing I can't imagine it hasn't been addressed.

I'm not finding anything obvious here at StackOverflow or from Google searches at large.  Am I just being dense and missing something obvious? Is there a standard/easy way to do this or is an image based fix (as suggested by one of the commenters of the above mentioned post) the way to go?

Comment: Still curious for an answer for the current version of Cake but the CSS solution suggested in the first comment on Mark's blog post seems to work well.

Comment: It may have been more than 2 years ago, but neither IE6 nor IE7 have gotten any better in the last two years, so issues they had then they'll still have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution from an anonymous poster on Mark Story's blog.  Just add this extra CSS definition right after the **form .required label:after** definition in your site.css file. (Around line 363 in CakePHP's default site.css file.)

```
div.required label {
  stupid-ie-be-more-funny: expression(this.doneReq ? '1' : (
      function(el) {el.innerHTML += '<span title="Required!" style="color:#f00;"> *</span>'; return el.doneReq=true;})(this));
}
```

This is working well in IE 6 and 7 for me.  I still like the red asterisks because they visually stand out more, expecially with the demographic I'm targeting (older users).

Answer (score 1):

you could just make the field bold or something like that

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact is that IE6 and IE7 do not support the CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes.

There is no way around this, and no hacks that I'm aware of to make them support it.

My preferred solution to this is to ignore it. Make them bold (as someone else has suggested) so that IE6 users get to see something, but frankly IE6 and IE7 are a small part of the browser market and rapidly getting smaller.

If you *must* give them an askerisk, then the best work around I can suggest is to replace it with an image instead of a '*'. Set your image as the `background-image` of the label, align it to one side with `x-repeat:none;`, and `padding` on the same side to move the label text out of the way, so the background image can be seen.

This method is often used for bullet points, so should work well for a 'required' marker. But I'd rather just stick with what you've got and pretend that IE6 and IE7 don't exist. It's not like they'll miss it or anything.

Comment: I wish I could ignore IE6 (I spit on you!) and IE7 (I kick you!) but the are (According to W3Schools anyway http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) still 10% of the market.  Can't ignore them quite yet.

Comment: @Dan Berlyoung - Please don't rely on w3schools for this sort of thing. A better resource is http://gs.statcounter.com/ ... but to be honest, the only really useful metric is your own site stats. Other peoeple's stats will never be accurate for you. But my point is that you can support these browsers without necessarily giving them 100% of the user experience. If the site works for them but they're missing a couple of the bells+whistles, is it really a problem? They can still use the site just fine, after all. And maybe the odd missing feature will encourage them to upgrade.